# Downloading my history?

Tags: support

2 questions please:

1. Is it possible to download all my own questions and my own answers that I have left from Stack Overflow?
2. Is it possible to download all my questions and the answers other people left on Stack Overflow? (I mean like the complete question pages (so my question, and all the answers, or just the best answer even) for all my questions).

Reason:  I want to do this because I have read on a website that Stack Overflow deletes old questions sometimes.

Comment: FYI, not many questions qualify for automatic deletion based on age. The ones that do probably wouldn't be useful for you to save. The rules are listed in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/131713).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194475/162102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will address the reason rather than the actual question which was answered already.

Old questions are not deleted from Stack Overflow just like that.

- Automatic deletion is done based on the conditions found in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/152859) - bottom line, if the question has answers it won't get deleted.
- Manual deletion (by moderator or community members) of questions is done only after the question is closed, thus marked as "does not fit" for the site.

In both cases, it's not worth keeping the question.

All in all, if you want to keep list of all your posts that will also preserve deleted posts, you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: Your first bullet point is exactly what I needed to know.  I don't want to lose good useful answers that I might need to visit again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. No. You could use the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), but there is no simple method for downloading.
2. No. You could use the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), but there is no simple method for downloading.

Comment: The [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) might help too.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a program to do this

https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-stack-dump.pl

but it works with the now defunct older version of the API.

Someone could update it to use the newer API, but let me re-ask the original question: now, 2+ years later, is there an easy way to download my questions/answers that don't involve screen scraping or using the API? Facebook, Twitter, and even Google all have this feature, so it would be really nice to have here too.

EDIT: I've now written a new program that downloads your questions/answers/comments on all StackExchange sites. It's doubtless buggy, assumes all your profiles are linked, and uses "page scraping", not the API:

https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/STACK/bc-suck-stack.pl